# How to drop a Redshift index?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I've got a superuser account and am trying to drop an index on a Redshift table with:

```
DROP INDEX my_table_pkey;
```

But I receive a `ERROR: Insufficient privileges`.  I'm confused because I can drop the table just fine, and I'm logged in as a Superuser.

```
# \du admin
                 List of roles
 Role name |      Attributes      | Member of 
-----------+----------------------+-----------
 admin     | Superuser, Create DB |
```

I've even tried

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO admin;
```

But I still get the insufficient privileges error when I try to drop the index.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html), Redshift doesn't support indexes so likely as not, there's not an actual index to drop.  Primary and foreign keys are for informational purposes only but are still recommend (see [Defining Constraints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html)) for the optimizer.  It is up to the application though, to actually enforce the keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can't drop index in Redshift.

but you can.

- create your table without the index.
- insert the data from the old table
- change the table name